# Subset/filter data.table by 2 paired vectors

Tags: r, data.table

How can I take a data.table object, and subset it conditionally on two columns by two paired vectors in another table. For instance I have a table of flights:

```
library(data.table)
library(nycflights13)
flights <- data.table(flights)
```

And I have another data.table containing my paired columns:

```
subDT <- data.table(sub_orig = c("EWR", "LGA"), sub_dest = c("IAH", "ATL"))
subDT
```

I wish to find and subset in `flights` those rows where the origin is `"EWR"` and the destination is `"IAH"` exactly (i.e. like using `&`) and also in the same query return the rows where origin is `"LGA"` and where the destination is `"ATL"`.

```
flights[dest %in% subDT[, sub_dest] & origin %in% subDT[, sub_orig]]
```

The above contains the data I want i.e. those pairings specified above, however it also contains pairings of `"EWR" & "ATL"` and `"LGA" & "IAH"` which I do not want.

I realise I can make a fake helper column (e.g. `paste(dest, origin)`) and select via `%in%` by that but I feel like there is a better approach, possibly some magic with `setkey` that currently escapes me?

N.B. my end use case will actually be using a combination of character vector as one column, and a numeric factor as the other, if that is important.

Comment: Apologies, what was the reason for marking as duplicate here? Though merge may offer a partial solution, your answers demonstrate there are more specific approaches not evident in the original question (`on`, `J`, multiple setkey)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try a binary join on the two columns which both efficient and implements the "*and*" logic

```
res <- setkey(flights, dest, origin)[J(subDT$sub_dest, subDT$sub_orig)]
res[, table(dest, origin)]
#      origin
# dest    EWR   LGA
#   ATL     0 10263
#   IAH  3973     0
```

Alternatively, with `v1.9.6+` you could also do

```
res <- flights[subDT, on = c(dest = "sub_dest", origin = "sub_orig")]
```

Comment: Or `merge(flights, subDT, by.x = c("origin", "dest"), by.y = c("sub_orig", "sub_dest"))`.

Comment: Yeah, it can be done with a `dplyr::right_join` too probably, but they after  an efficient `data.table` solution I believe.

Comment: `merge.data.table` should be rather efficient, no?

Comment: I'm not sure if it was optimized since, but I believe it is inferior to a binary join.

Comment: It has been improved in 1.9.6. See the documentation.

Comment: From `help("merge.data.table")`: "In versions < v1.9.6, if the specified columns in by was not the key (or head of the key) of x or y, then a copy is first rekeyed prior to performing the merge. This was less performant and memory inefficient."

Comment: Yeah, you are right, found this in the readme too just now.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion, I think I understand most of this, except for the part where you explicitly reference the `J` argument in the middle?

Comment: Additionally, using the `on` method gives an error when including it for my actual use case: `Error in forderv(x, by = rightcols) : 
  'by' value -2147483648 out of range [1,7]` I'm pretty sure I have the right version, your example worked for me. The other method is fine though. Thank you.

Comment: That error is usually happens when you are specifying the column names incorrectly. It works perfectly fine on the provided data sets.

Comment: Exactly that, thank you again.

Comment: Just to update on the mentioned `forderv` error message, it has been already improved in [#1376](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1376). @DaveRGP

Comment: You'll need the devel version from GH though.